# Verb tense use with the locution "every day" in this sentence

Tags: tenses, any-every

This sentence "The customer service representatives (had fielded) more than 150 calls every day regarding the new name of the company", is part of an exercice where we have to correct a word or phrase in each sentence

the word to correct here is the one between brackets, it's obviously wrong, and our teacher told us that you have to put it in the simple present (fields) because of the locution "every day" present in the sentence, but I was not convinced and I don't have much confidence in our teacher because I know she's not very competent, so I decided to browse the web to search for answers and so here I am ...

I felt like we can also say (have fielded) or maybe even (have been fielding) in the sentence, and now that I think about it maybe we can also say (are fielding), but I am not sure ...

Can someone tell me which one is correct please ? And why ?

Thanks

Comment: You are quite right. One could use any active tense of the verb *to field* in that space - *fields, was fielding, will field, has fielded, had fielded, will have fielded*.

Comment: "Every day" is functioning as an adverb, and the sentence is unchanged, from a verb tense standpoint, if it's removed entirely.  The whole exercise is bogus.

Comment: This is closely related to another recent question which also uses "every day", [Present progressive instead of present simple](/q/355642). The first example at that question demonstrates that choice of tense can change the meaning. Without knowing the meaning it's not possible to choose the right tense.

Comment: Also, it's obviously not "fields" or "had fielded" because "the customer service representatives" is plural.

Answer (score 1):

I would use "are fielding". I guess it's more of a happening-now situation that is occurring every day since the time they changed the name of the company! http://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/present-continuous-use.html